# How to insert thousand separators only before the decimal separator

Tags: regex, string, vim, replace

I use this regex to put thousand separators in a string:

```
while matchstr(mystr, '\(\d\)\(\d\{3}\)\(\D\|\s\|$\)') != ''
    let mystr = substitute(mystr, '\(\d\)\(\d\{3}\)\(\D\|\s\|$\)', '\1.\2\3', 'g')
endwhile
```

For

```
let mystr = '2000000'
```

the code above gives

```
2.000.000
```

The problem is when there is a decimal separator, it also puts thousand separators in the fractional part of a number after the decimal separator (which is the comma hereafter).

For example,

```
let mystr = '2000000,2346'
```

leads to

```
2.000.000,2.346
```

while I want it to be

```
2.000.000,2346
```

I tried to adapt the above code but didn't find a satisfiable solution.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following call to the `substitute()` function instead of the whole
loop listed in the question.

```
substitute(s, '\(\d,\d*\)\@<!\d\ze\(\d\{3}\)\+\d\@!', '&.', 'g')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works great! I'm trying to understand what you've done but it is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this (work for positive integer only):**

**Find with**

```
(?<=[0-9])(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))
```

**Replace with**

```
,
```

---

I've not tried over `vim` whether it would work or not. But the pattern is PCRE compatible.

---

**Explanation**

```
<!--
(?<=[0-9])(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))

Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=[0-9])»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))»
   Match the regular expression below «(?:[0-9]{3})+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{3}»
         Exactly 3 times «{3}»
   Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?![0-9])»
      Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
-->
```

Comment: Tnx Cylian, I can't find out the vim variant. The prce regex is very different of the vim regex

Comment: I personally never have used ``vim`` before but, its help file ``usr_27.txt>>section 27.4`` describes that ``{`` must be escaped, like ``\{``. So, you could try: ``(?<=[0-9])(?=(?:[0-9]\{3})+(?![0-9]))``...

Comment: `?<=` --> `\@<=`, I changed everything to the vim regex but it doesn't work. The Zero-width assertions are different in vim. I suppose also where they have to be. P.e. changing `?<=` in `\@<=` gives the error: nothing follows `\@<=`